# Cleaning DataSets! Creating a new variable based on date range of another variable

Tags: r, variables, data-cleaning

I have two data sets that need some cleaning for easier analysis and they both have to do something very similar. Let's start with data set A.

A looks like this:

```
ID  Test.Date   Test.Score

1   9/22/14        25
2   1/3/2015       50
3   3/17/2015      52
4   6/1/2015       56
```

So, what I need are 3 new variables that pull the score from Test.Score based on date ranges. One range will be 8/01/2014-11/01/2014, another 12/01/2014-3/25/2015, and the third 4/01/2015-6/30/2015. These correlate to Fall, Winter, and Spring data collections. So the new dataframe should look like this:

```
ID  Test.Date   Test.Score   Test.Fall   Test.Winter   Test.Spring

1   9/22/14        25           25
2   1/3/2015       50                        50
3   3/17/2015      52                        52
4   6/1/2015       56                                       56
```

Preferably NA's will fill the spots in the new variable columns if a particular score was not collected during that date range. Does this make sense?

Data set B is similar except it's got 3 dates per ID and 3 scores. So it looks like this:

```
 ID  Test.Date1   Test.Date2   Test.Date3   Test.Score1   Test.Score.2   Test.Score3

1   9/22/14       1/3/2015        6/1/2015      25            30            55
2   9/22/14       10/3/2015        6/1/2015      26            31            66
3   9/22/14       1/3/2015        6/1/2015      25            39            63
4   9/22/14       1/3/2015        6/1/2015      22            29            56
```

B needs to create 3 new columns called Test.Fall, Test.Winter, Test.Spring, and pull the values according to the same data range as above. Now, you may be wondering, why not just rename the test score columns? Because some participants took two tests within weeks of eachother (see sample ID #2). We need one test per Fall, Winter, Spring. So if Test.Date1 was in September, and Test.Date2 was October, that participant ID simply won't have a Test.Winter score.

Do I need to clarify anything?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the code you've already tried to solve this problem and where you had difficulties.

Comment: Adding on to what @josilber said, providing us with a useable sample of your data, or mock data, would be helpful. See `dput`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

A = 
  data_frame(
    ID = 1:4,
    Test.Date = c("9/22/2014", "1/3/2015", "3/17/2015", "6/1/2015") %>% mdy,
    Test.Score = c(25, 50, 52, 56))

classify = function(date_vector)
  ifelse(
    date_vector %>% between(mdy("8/01/2014"), mdy("11/01/2014")),
    "Fall",
    ifelse(
      date_vector %>% between(mdy("12/01/2014"), mdy("3/25/2015")),
      "Winter",
      ifelse(
        date_vector %>% between(mdy("4/01/2015"), mdy("6/30/2015")),
        "Spring",
        "Other"))) %>%
  paste("Test", ., sep = ".")


result.A = 
  A %>%
  mutate(Season = classify(Test.Date)) %>%
  spread(Season, Test.Score) %>%
  select(-Test.Date) %>%
  left_join(A)

B = 
  data_frame(
    ID = 1:4,
    Test.Date1 = 
      c("9/22/14", "9/22/14", "9/22/14", "9/22/14") %>% mdy,
    Test.Date2 = 
      c("1/3/2015", "10/3/2015", "1/3/2015 ", "1/3/2015 ") %>% mdy,
    Test.Date3 = 
      c("6/1/2015", "6/1/2015", " 6/1/2015",  "6/1/2015") %>% mdy,
    Test.Score1 = c(25, 26, 25, 22),
    Test.Score2 = c(30, 31, 39, 29),
    Test.Score3 = c(55, 66, 63, 56))

result.B =
  B %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
  mutate(type = 
           variable %>% stri_sub(6, -2),
         rep = 
           variable %>% stri_sub(-1)) %>%
  select(-variable) %>%
  spread(type, value) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, tz = "UTC", origin = origin),
         Season = classify(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID, Season) %>%
  summarize(Score = mean(Score)) %>%
  spread(Season, Score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your data set A problem using `base` R

```
# Construct Test Data
mydata <- data.frame(ID = c(1:4),
                     Test.Date = c("9/22/14", "1/3/2015", "3/17/2015", "6/1/2015"),
                     Test.Score = c(25, 50, 52, 56))

# Format dates
mydata$Test.Date <- as.character(mydata$Test.Date)
mydata$newDate <- as.Date(mydata$Test.Date, "%m/%d/%y")
mydata$newDate[2:4] <- as.Date(mydata$Test.Date[2:4], "%m/%d/%Y")

#Classify Tests
mydata$Test.Fall = ifelse(mydata$newDate > "2014-08-01" & mydata$newDate < "2014-11-01", mydata$Test.Score, NA)
mydata$Test.Winter = ifelse(mydata$newDate > "2014-12-01" & mydata$newDate < "2015-03-25", mydata$Test.Score, NA)
mydata$Test.Spring = ifelse(mydata$newDate > "2015-04-01" & mydata$newDate < "2015-06-30", mydata$Test.Score, NA)
```

Your problem with data set B isn't exactly clear:

> We need one test per Fall, Winter, Spring. So if Test.Date1 was in September, and Test.Date2 was October, that participant ID simply won't have a Test.Winter score.

If there are two test dates that fall within the Fall date range, then *which* test score should go in Test.Fall? The higher score? The more recent score? The average? Happy to update my answer when you provide that information.